# TensorFlow reduce_sum returns partially incorrect output given a large input

Tags: tensorflow

I am having an issue where `reduce_sum` in TensorFlow returns incorrect values on input larger than a certain size.

Specifically, if I generate a random 64x512x4096x2 tensor and compare `reduce_sum` over the 3rd axis with manually adding the 0th and 1st elements in the 3rd dimension, as expected, the resulting tensors are the same in all 134217728 elements.

However, if I do the exact same steps with a **65**x512x4096x2 tensor, the resulting tensors agree on the first 134217728 elements but differ in the remaining 2097152.

I have tried this on several different machines and GPUs. Here is a self-contained snippet that should reproduce the results:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
  test = tf.random_uniform([64, 512, 4096, 2])
  print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_int32(tf.logical_not(tf.equal(test[:,:,:,0] + test[:,:,:,1], tf.reduce_sum(test, axis=3))))).eval())
  # 0
  print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_int32(tf.equal(test[:,:,:,0]+test[:,:,:,1], tf.reduce_sum(test, axis=3)))).eval())
  # 134217728

  test = tf.random_uniform([65, 512, 4096, 2])
  print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_int32(tf.logical_not(tf.equal(test[:,:,:,0] + test[:,:,:,1], tf.reduce_sum(test, axis=3))))).eval())
  # 2097152
  print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_int32(tf.equal(test[:,:,:,0] + test[:,:,:,1], tf.reduce_sum(test, axis=3)))).eval())
  # 134217728
```

Comment: This is a bug. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22123